# "have read and understand" or "have read and understood"

Tags: tense

I came across this when I was surfing Stack overflow:

[image]

I have two questions here:

1. Is this "have read and understand" appropriate? Because in my opinion, "have read" means action took place in past, whereas "understand" means it is in present. Isn't it a tense mismatch? I think it should be "have read and understood".
2. If it is appropriate, then how should I interpret the whole sentence? In what tenses should I consider these actions?

I googled for this, but didn't get answers to above questions. Detailed explanation would be very helpful.

Comment: I have been meaning to ask this question for quite some time now, but I am used to forgetting it every time.

Comment: It's ((have read) and understand) vs (have (read and understood))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the form with *understand* emphasises that I understand it right now. The form with *have understood* merely states the fact that two events took place in the past. Of course in the normal state of affairs if you understood it in the past you still understand it now but sometime people forget.

Either is correct thought and effectively mean the same just the emphasis is slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

Have read so you presently understand. Whereas if you understood reading would not clarify understanding

Comment: Can you edit to explain what you mean in more detail? At the moment it is hard to grasp.